# Print style sheets + links

Tags: html, css, printing

When I print my page links are converted to the actual URL rather than what the link contains, is there a way I can stop this behavior, as I have images wrapped in links and I don't want the links to display when a user prints the page

Thanks

Comment: Presumably there is something in your print stylesheet that is doing this? (I'm guessing on the basis of the question title.) Why not just remove that from the stylesheet? If there's more to it than that, then please make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a sensible default to *print* the URLs - after all you can't click or hover over the links on a printed page.

In fact, [this link](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/improvingprint)  is an 'A List Apart' article on how to display URLs better.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you remove your print stylesheet and print the page?

If that fixes it then there is probably something wrong with the stylesheet. Please post all rules that relate to links so we can check.

If it still prints the URLs, then it's likely an issue with your system - the browser, printer, etc. Are you printing to a real paper printer, or something like a PDF printer?